# Componente uniQuery da Unidac não retorna valor do keygenerator

Tags: delphi, query, firebird, chave-primária

Estou com problemas em inserir no Firebird usando o componente uniQuery (Delphi 7 com Unidac) da Devart. O campo que e chave primária está nos fieds da query e a configuração do componente está assim:

```
CAMPO_ID : 
ProviderFlags > pfKey > True
Required > False

Query:
Options > RequiredFields > False
UniQuery Editor > Options > Provider Interbase > GeneratorMode > gmInsert
UniQuery Editor > Options > Provider Interbase > KeyGenerator > Meu_sequence
```

Mesmo com essa configuração, ocorre um erro ao tentar gravar.

> Erro: viola restrição de chave estrangeira

Com uniTable da certo, mas eu preciso que seja com uma uniQuery.